# Docker - PHP 8.0 with iconv

Tags: php, docker, iconv

i am learning with DOCKER and i want start php server with PHP 8.0 with ICONV.

I use this dockerfile.

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm-alpine

WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Setup GD extension
RUN apk add --no-cache \
      freetype \
      libjpeg-turbo \
      libpng \
      freetype-dev \
      libjpeg-turbo-dev \
      libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
      --with-freetype=/usr/include/ \
      --with-jpeg=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-enable gd \
    && apk del --no-cache \
      freetype-dev \
      libjpeg-turbo-dev \
      libpng-dev \
    && rm -rf /tmp/*

RUN apk add libzip-dev

# Install intl extension
RUN apk add --no-cache \
    icu-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl \
      iconv  \
    && docker-php-ext-enable intl \
    && rm -rf /tmp/*

# Install iconv extension
RUN apk add --no-cache --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing gnu-libiconv
ENV LD_PRELOAD /usr/lib/preloadable_libiconv.so php

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip bcmath
```

Everythink is OK but iconv is disabled.

```
iconv
iconv support   enabled
iconv implementation    unknown
iconv library version   unknown
```

```
ICONV extension Disabled or does not work properly
ICONV extension is required and must work properly.
```

Please, can you tell me what is wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Old thread, but you are missing the iconv at the docker-php-ext-install

```
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip bcmath iconv
```